# Trigonometry equation $\cos(2x)-\cos(3x)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$\cos(2x)-\cos(3x)=0$$

I am trying to solve this equation but get stuck every time in the middle of the exercise. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: But this isn't a site to ask such problems...

Answer (score 4):

Notice, we have $$\cos(3x)=\cos(2x)$$ 
$$3x=2n\pi\pm 2x$$
Where, $n$ is any integer

Now, we have the following solutions

$$3x=2n\pi+2x\implies \color{red}{x=2n\pi}$$
or 
$$3x=2n\pi-2x\implies \color{red}{x=\frac{2n\pi}{5}}$$

Edit -1 (Thanks @Bernard)

> Observe the second set of solutions contains the first.

Comment: Unexpected donwvote for the best answer...

Comment: I was waiting for that

Comment: @velutluna: yes it does, with a $\pm$.

Comment: @velutluna Did you miss the "or $3x=2n\pi-2x$" ?

Comment: I see! My mistake!

Comment: Atleast I use to solve equations like this when I was at school.

Comment: (+1) Observe the second set of solutions contains the first.

Comment: Yep we can furthermore simplify it

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\cos 2x - \cos 3x = 2 \sin \frac{5x}{2}\sin\frac{x}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\cos(x)-\cos(y)=-2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right)$$